# PHP Image upload not working after SSL certificate installed, getting 500 Internal Server error

Tags: php, ssl, image-upload

When trying to upload an image I am getting 500 Internal Server Error since having SSL certificate installed

Permissions on the folders have been set to public as I suspected it was that permissions were only applied to me when uploading using Filezilla

Comment: The "500 Internal Server Error" is a generic error message indicating that something has gone wrong on the server side while processing your request. But here are some possible solutions you can try; Check server logs, Review file permissions, Verify SSL certificate installation, Check PHP settings, Test with a smaller image, Contact your hosting provider

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  I will check with the hosting provider.